# Write to rails database from my ruby script that is running by cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I have a ruby script that is running every 24 hours via cron. It just does some scraping of a site and saves the data to a CSV file. Instead, I want to write it directly to a rails db so I can use it from within my rails app.

I have tried calling the class such as `Class.new` but this does not work. How can I write this directly into a rails db?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake

Answer (score 1):

You can run class methods in your Rails app from Cron like this:

```
0 0 * * * cd path/to/your/app; RAILS_ENV=production script/runner "Scapper.process"
```